# How can you simplify this equation?$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt{1-x}}-\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{2\sqrt{(1+x)^3}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am going through Calculus Made Easy by Silvanus Thompson and at the end of this walk-through problem, he simplify his answer to the equation shown below. I tried many ways to understand which step he took to arrive to that simplified form but I just can't figure it out. I understand every step before but not this one

1.$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt{1-x}}-\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{2\sqrt{(1+x)^3}}$$

And below is what Thompson gets in the book when he simplifies it:

2.$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

I tried to multiply the top equation(1) by a common denominator for example:

$\frac{-\sqrt{(1+x)^3}-\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt{1-x}}{2\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{(1+x)^3}}$

which ultimately lead me to $\frac{x}{\sqrt1-x^4}$

Does anyone know what to do in this situation?

Comment: It's an algebra error on your part. You over multiplied both numerators. Note that the "gcd" of the two denominators is $\sqrt{1+x}$ so you only need to multiply by the extra bits that aren't that.

Comment: Oh yes, you are completely right. I did not see that you could simplify $\sqrt{(1+x)^3} \sqrt{1-x}= \sqrt{(1+x)^2(1+x)}\sqrt{1-x}= (1+x)\sqrt{(1+x)(1-x)}=(1+x)\sqrt{1-x^2}$
Thank you!